# nested json file with dictionary into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a json file as

```
{
    "Date": 2017,
    "count": 88,         
    "demographics":  [
        {
            "key": "age",
            "value": "20-30"
        },
        {
            "key": "education",
            "value": 'bachelor'
        },
        {
            "key": "income",
            "value": "70-80"
        },
        {
            "key": "location",
            "value": "USA"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use the code below to convert it into csv file. It gives me a dataframe with 3 columns of *Date*, *count*, and *demographics*, but the output I need is a dataframe with 6 columns of *Date*, *Count*, *age*, *education*, *income*, and *location*.

```
with open(r'Sample.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
dfNormalized=json_normalize(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `apply` with `pd.Serise`:

```
d={
     "Date": 2017,
     "count": 88,
     "demographics":  [
                    {
           "key": "age",
           "value": "20-30"
        },
                    {
           "key": "education",
           "value": 'bachelor'
        },
                    {
           "key": "income",
           "value": "70-80"
        },
                    {
           "key": "location",
           "value": "USA"
        }
        ]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)

A=(df.demographics.apply(pd.Series).T.loc['value'].to_frame().\
    set_index(df.demographics.apply(pd.Series).T.loc['key']).T).\
       rename_axis(None,1).reset_index(drop=True)


pd.concat([df.drop('demographics',1).loc[0].to_frame().T,A],1)
    Out[273]: 
       Date  count    age education income location
    0  2017     88  20-30  bachelor  70-80      USA
```